# The impulse on a wall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

If a ball was thrown to a wall, How could we calculate the impulse on the wall ?

For example, if I throw a $2kg$ ball with $ 4m/s$, and it returned with the same speed but in the opposite direction, so the impulse on the ball would be $16N.s$.

According to the conservation to the momentum the impulse on the wall is also $16N.s$ ,But the wall is stable hence ,$Δv = 0$. In other word the impulse on the wall should be zero Depending on $I = mΔv$.

This confuses me and I don't know what I am missing.

Please Help

Comment: You are dealing with zeros and infinities. A rigid wall is taken lim $m \to \infty$. So $I$ can be whatever it needs to be.

Comment: @PaulChilds ,Sorry, But what you are trying to say in not clear to me, I can't see any limit here, Is it zero or 16 and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the mass of the ball be $m$ and that of the wall (and the Earth) be $M$.
The initial velocity of the wall is $\vec v_{\rm i}$ and that of the wall is zero.
The final velocity of the wall is $\vec v_{\rm f}$ and that of the wall is $\vec V_{\rm f}$.

Assume that the ball and wall system has no eternal forces acting on it then applying the conservation of linear momentum gives $m\vec v_{\rm i} = m\vec v_{\rm f} +\vec MV_{\rm f}$.

So the impulse on the ball is $m\vec v_{\rm f}- m\vec v_{\rm i} = m\Delta \vec v$ and the impulse on the wall is $M\vec V_{\rm f} = M\Delta \vec V$  and of the same magnitude as the impulse on the ball.

As $M\gg m$ then in terms of the magnitudes of the changes in velocities $\Delta V \ll \Delta v$ and in many cases the approximation $\Delta V \approx 0$ is made so to a very good degree of accuracy the ball does rebound with the same speed as it had before hitting the wall if the collision is elastic.

Comment: ,When you say that $\delta V$ is not zero ,This means that a very very very small change in momentum occur to the earth. $\delta V = \frac {16}{M}$.Is this right ?

Comment: @MohammadAlshareef The magnitude of the momentum change of the wall/Earth is the same as that of the ball but because the wall/Earth has a mass so much greater than the ball the magnitude of the change in velocity of the wall/Earth is very much smaller than that of the ball.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, its because $I=m\Delta v$ applies to the *net* impulse.  The wall transfers nearly all of the impulse down into the ground, and into the earth, so the net impulse on the wall is nearly 0, even though the impulse on the wall from the ball is $16 \text N\cdot \text s$.

Technically speaking, this will actually change the rotation of the earth *slightly*, accounting for this transfer of momentum.  Practically speaking, however, this change in velocity is so minuscule compared to our uncertainty in measurement that we handwave it away.  It's not exactly 0, but its close enough for us to at least ignore it.

And, of course, we cant change the rate of rotation of the earth meaningfully with this trick.  Nearly all ways we generate the momentum of the ball in the first place impart momentum in the planet one direction, and then the impact with the wall (transferred to the ground) negates it.

Answer (score 0):

The impulse on the wall and the attached planet (the Earth) is 16 N$\cdot$ s. The mass of the earth $M$ is rather large. The change in velocity of the earth is $16/M$ ms$^{-1}$ which is rather small. For all intents and purposes  this small number is zero. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct ,mathematicly ,but actual situation is different  ,since mass of wall including earth is very large, impulse of 16N cannot change its momentum,at the same time when you look at the ball,it experience the same impulse of 16N which is enough to change it,s velocity and momentum.

Answer (score 0):

The wall is attached to the Earth and, thus, the two are assumed to form a single rigid structure with a large mass m. As $I=m\delta v=16 N.s$, $\delta v$ has to be much small and is practically 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ft=m(v-u)
Note:
The ball rebounce in the opposite direction
Therefore
Ft=m(v-(-u)) =m(v+u)
Given;
m=2kg
v=4m/s
Ft=2(4+4)
Ft=2(8)=16

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) to type formulae.